# Populating ASP.Net DetailsView DropDownList with default value when entering Add mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, default-value, populate, code-behind

We would like to populate a DropDownList with a default value that is obtained from a variable when the user goes into "Add" mode on an ASP.Net DetailsView from a VB.Net code-behind file. Can you show me how to get it populated?

Here is the markup for the DropDownList we wish to populate:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class:" SortExpression="ClassID">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="DropDownListClass" 
            Runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
            DataTextField = "ClassName"
            DataValueField="ID"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
            ForeColor="Blue">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorEditClass" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListClass" 
            ErrorMessage="Please select a Class here." Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" 
            SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic">

        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    </EditItemTemplate>

    <InsertItemTemplate>

        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="DropDownListClass" 
            Runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
            DataTextField = "ClassName"
            DataValueField="ID"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
            ForeColor="Blue">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorInsertClass" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListClass" 
            ErrorMessage="Please select a Class here." Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" 
            SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic">

        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </InsertItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="DropDownListClass" 
            Runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
            DataTextField = "ClassName"
            DataValueField="ID"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
            Enabled="false"
            ForeColor="Blue"
            Font-Bold="true"> 
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

We are using this in the code-behind file to populate the variable that will contain the default value:

```
Function GetValueFromDropDownListClassItem() As String

    Dim strValueToReturn As String
    Dim drpValue As DropDownList

    drpValue = DetailsView.FindControl("DropDownListClass")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(drpValue.Text) Then
        strValueToReturn = ""
    Else
        strValueToReturn = drpValue.SelectedItem.Text
    End If

    Return strValueToReturn
End Function
```

We just want to use this value and have the DropDownList pre-selected with the value from this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

You mean like this?

```
Protected Sub dropdown_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim list As DropDownList = TryCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim value as String = GetValueFromDropDownListClassItem()
    If list IsNot Nothing And value IsNot "" Then
        list.SelectedValue = value
    End If
End Sub
```

Old message: 
Please try the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="DropDownListClass" 
    Runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
    DataTextField = "ClassName"
    DataValueField="ID"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
    AppendDataBoundItems="True"
    ForeColor="Blue">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Please select</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Please note the AppendDataBoundItems true and listItem

Comment: Thanks for the reply but we are looking not to add a new value, but to select an existing value in the DropDownList obtained from a variable that contains the value to select.

Comment: Something like I posted in my Edit?